# Can I use textedit on mac as the text editor for writing c program?

Tags: c, terminal, text-editor, textedit

I am trying to learn how to program using just a text editor and terminal on mac. I was trying to use `textEdit` as text editor and I even changed the format to plain text so that it doesn't use the `rtf` format but even after saving it with .c extension, each time i use the `gcc hello.c -o main` command on terminal it shows this:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Is it because we can't use textEdit for this purpose? and if so, why can't we use it?

Comment: Did you install xcode?

Comment: The problem is not with TextEdit not saving the file correctly, but that you don´t seem to have a correctly installed compiler. Try installing XCode and its command line tools.

Comment: @MagnusReftel Most probably this is the right answer, please make it a real one.

Comment: I just used TextEdit to create a `.c` file on my Mac, and I was able to compile it successfully.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're saying I don't have gcc installed right? Do I have to install XCode to get gcc? Also, you mentioned installing its command line tools too so if I just install gcc independently will I still have to install more stuff other than just the compiler? Also, thank you for that suggestion! @MagnusReftel

Comment: You can get the [command line tools](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/index.html) without the exoquads of useless stuff that takes over your hard-drive that is xCode. You probably want Homebrew to update. TextEdit is an annoying editor to code in, but BBEdit, Sublime, VSC, Atom, _etc_ work.

Comment: And here is some background information why `gcc` by default actually uses the command line tools: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324947

Comment: Thank you everyone I'll try and install gcc then

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with TextEdit not saving the file correctly, but that you don´t seem to have a correctly installed compiler. Try installing XCode and its command line tools from the Mac App Store.